Rust "cannot return value referencing temporary value" static ref Mutex Vec slice
How to return a slice of a static Mutex<Vec>? Obviously I thought adding "static" to &[i64] would suffice. I've seen solutions with .iter().skip().take().collect() and .iter().map().collect() however those don't appear to compile either. Would prefer to return a slice (&[T]) rather than returning a vector (Vec<T>). Thanks!
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::sync::{Mutex, MutexGuard};
use std::vec::Vec;

const CAPACITY: usize = 1048576;

lazy_static! {
    static ref integer_keys: Mutex<Vec<[usize; 2]>> = Mutex::new(vec![[0, 0]; CAPACITY + 1]);
    static ref integer_values: Mutex<Vec<i64>> = Mutex::new(Vec::with_capacity(CAPACITY + 1));
}

pub fn integers_get(n: u64) -> &'static [i64] {
    let keys = integer_keys.lock().unwrap();
    return &integer_values.lock().unwrap()[keys[n as usize][0]..keys[n as usize][1]];
}


When you lock a mutex it returns a "mutex guard" that must exist for the duration that you're accessing that value. The mutex guard (the temporary value) needs to be returned as well so that when it is dropped it will release the lock on the mutex.
